# getting icon's error in rails_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, icons, rails-admin

I added  font-awesome in /assets/images/fonts.

-it is working fine in local server.

But, i am getting icon as squerbox in live server and i am getting 404 for font-awesome in browser console.

```
GET http://domain_name/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0 isAdShaped @ ad.js:247elementIsAd @ ad.js:219(anonymous function) @ ad.js:344findAds @ ad.js:343extractAds @ ad.js:785extractAdsWrapper @ ad.js:779
GET http://domain_name/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.4.0 
GET http://domain_name/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.4.0 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a 404 error, try to add to application.rb or production.rb this line to precompile this kind of assets:

```
config.assets.precompile += ["*.ttf", "*.woff", "*.svg", "*.eot"]
```

If this not solve your problem. Try run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` To see actual problem. There may be some issue with other files.

Similar issue [here](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails/issues/38) with some solution.